# how to use awk command where the file is perl variable

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, awk

1. Unable to run the awk command in perl script and my file is variable.
2. I have tried in different ways like use system(`awk '/"">/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr' $download_content`) and store the output in array but no luck.

   ```
   $filter = `awk '/"">/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr' $download_content`;
   ```
3. here $download_content is a webpage i.e in html format and i need to extract the search pattern line and its next 6th line.

Comment: Why not just do it all in perl? **Especially** if you're dealing with HTML, since perl has many HTML parsing modules to choose from to do a proper job.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using [`IPC::Run3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3):

```
use IPC::Run3;

# [...]

my @cmd = ('awk', '/"">/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr');
my $in = $download_content;
my $out;
run3 \@cmd, \$in, \$out; 
$filter = $out;
```

Alternatively, you can do it in `perl` (not calling `awk`):

```
my @lines = split /\n/, $download_content;
my %nr;
my $NR = 0;
my $filter = "";
for ( @lines ) {
    if ( /"">/ ) {
        $nr{$NR}++;
        $nr{$NR + 6}++;
    }
    $filter .= "$_\n" if $nr{$NR};
    $NR++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write something like:

```
awk '/"">/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr' XXXX
```

Then `awk` expects "XXXX" to be the name of a file that it should work on. But (as I understand it) that's not the situation that you have. It sounds to me as though "XXXX" is the actual data that you want to work on. In that case, you need to pipe the data into `awk`. The easiest option is to use `echo`:

```
echo XXXX | awk '/"">/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+6]}; NR in nr'
```

You should be able to do the same thing using Perl' `system()` function.

But it might be simpler to reimplement your `awk` code as Perl.